# Selenium span click works on 1 calendar but not the second calendar (Python)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to select 2 dates from 2 dropdown calendars.

My code below works on the first calendar `<span>` but not on the second calendar `<span>`. 
The HTML code is exactly the same?

I am using:

`return_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text() = " Day "]').click()`

HTML layout

**Calendar 1:** *Searching for span containing text ( 30 )* - **Works.**

```
<td aria-selected="true" class="datepicker__day" role="gridcell">
<span data-ts-automation="datepicker-day-30"> 30 </span>
<!---->
</td>
```

**Calendar 2:** *Searching for span containing text ( 14 )* - **Error: Element is not interactable.**

```
<td aria-selected="true" class="datepicker__day" role="gridcell">
<!---->
<span data-ts-automation="datepicker-day-14"> 14 </span>
</td>
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but if that's the April calendar then 30 is in the future and 14 is in the past -- maybe that app doesn't let you select past dates?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The 30th date is in April 2020 & the 14th date is in May 2020.

Comment: As a debugging step, can you print the element before clicking on it?  Maybe you're getting some other element with text `14` that you didn't expect.

Comment: Are you able to click on the element yourself, by hand, in a plain browser session?

Comment: I am able to click the element myself by hand on chrome browser. If I print the element it gives me a session and element ID. Type: <class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because selenium searches from TopLeft of page and it is finding the return date in first calendar which is not interactable at that moment. You need to use indexing here to tell selenium to look in second calender. Use the below xpath:

```
return_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[text() = ' Day '])[2]").click()
```

Hope this helps :)